# Non-model field from data in Serializer DRF

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize an object where I would pass data which are non-model field into the serializer

```
    data = {
        'field1': 'abc',
        'field2': 123,
    }

    serializer = UserSerializer(
        user,
        context={"request": request},
        data=request.data,
        partial=True,
    )
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    result = serializer.validated_data
```

where I have a UserSerializer as such

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'field1',
            'field2',
        )
```

But I am getting empty `DefaultDict()` from the `serializer.validated_data`

Comment: you can't validate (call `is_valid()`) unleass you provide a **`data`** argument

Comment: are you sure that you need to provide `user` instance or some `dict` like object?

Answer (score 2):

you need to define that `serializerMethod`. Like

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'field1',
            'field2',
        )

    def get_field1(self, obj):
        value = self.context['request'].data.get('field1')
        return value
    def get_field2(self, obj):
        value = self.context['request'].data.get('field2')
        return value
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't call get_field1 in my code and I am still getting empty OrderedDict()

Comment: ok, i got that. `searializerMethodField` is read_only field by default. whenever you are passing `partial`=True into this , both of these fields are ignored for `patch` request. I don't think you need a model serializer even for this. If you need to make sure what you actually want, seems like you just want customize serialize data.